# Filter search by tags with python redisearch client

Tags: python, python-3.x, redisearch

I have an index with a TagField, created like this

```
create_index([TextField("enc_id"), TextField("title", 2.0), TagField("tags")])
```

I would add a document like this.

```
add_document(title = "meh, lol", tags = "python,C")
```

I search like this. It has a few fields that don't need to be searched, so I limited fields to search.

```
Query(query_string='meh').limit_fields(title)
```

What I want is to also filter results by some tags. For example, I have documents with tags like python, C, Java and I only want documents to be returned that has the tag 'C'.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it :D.

I basically tried to execute pure redis-cli commands with the python client. Didn't know how :/

But this worked. I can use **@** in the query string. Just like we do in cli.

```
Query("@title:meh @tags:{java}")
```